# How to define a function for later use in Mathematica

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica, package

I'm just getting started on Mathematica and trying to define a function for later use. The function is:

```
test[x_]:=x^2
```

While I don't close Mathematica, I can use the function on my notebooks but when I close it, the function disappears, I tried to save a `.m` file with it but It didn't work. What do I do?

Comment: In which sense it didn't work ?

Comment: Did you save it in your notebook (.nb) file before closing mathematica?  When you reopen Mathematica is the function still there.  Have you tried making the cell in which it is defined an automatic initialization cell?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you misunderstand how to save/import.  Here's the process that should work:

- Define a function like you have above, Save As `test.m` (In Mathematica 8, it won't "look like" you saved it, the open notebook is still "Untitled-1", but it did save.  You can verify however you like.)
- Open a new notebook
- Import your library like this: `Import["C:\\users\\joeblow\\documents\\Mathematica Notebooks\\test.m"]`
- You should now be able to access the `test` function

Does this not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Open Mathematica, create a new Notebook

```
test[x_]=x^2;
DumpSave["test.mx",test];
```

You even don't have to save the Notebook, just close Mathematica.(But remember, in this case, you lose chance to modify the function forever) Then reopen Mathematica, create a new Notebook

```
DumpGet["test.mx"];
test[5]
(*25*)
```